# How to echo variable value outside of the function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

```
<?php
function ybr_client_results(){
    $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');

?>
```

How to echo this $client_details value outside of the function

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You can return $client_details in ybr_client_results function. then do echo the function ybr_client_results().

Comment: How to pass this value ($client_details) to a included php file in wordpress plugin

Comment: @Hari it also return 0

Comment: `function ybr_client_results(){
  $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];
  return $client_details;
  die();
}
$client_details = ybr_client_results();
echo $client_details;
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');`

Comment: And it return variable value with 0

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [**global**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variable

**Example**

```
$client_details = "";
function ybr_client_results(){
    global $client_details;
    $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<?php
$client_details = "";
function ybr_client_results(){
    $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];
    die();
}
echo $client_details;
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create variable outside of function, and in function you have to create same name variable with global.

```
<?php
$client_datails;
function ybr_client_results(){
    global $client_details;
    $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible. My solution is you have to save these value to database(such as wp_options) then use the method get_option to echo this value.